# How to track when a variable is initialized and eventually destroyed

Tags: ruby

Presumably i have a instance var `@foo`

It is set inside `def initialize` so i can track when it is initialized.

However i also need to track when it is destroyed.

Are there some "hook" for this? Just like `method_defined` or `included?`

Something like `instance_variable_destroyed foo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically hook the garbage collector.
You need to use a define_finalizer.

```
define_finalizer(@foo, proc {|id| puts "Destroyed #{id}"})
```

Comment: ok, seems to work, for strings. why wont it register a finalizer for symbols?

Comment: At least on all currently existing implementations of Ruby, `Symbol`s are never garbage collected, therefore the finalizer would never run anyway.

Comment: Note that this *does not* tell you when the variable goes out of scope. It tells you when the object *the variable points to* gets garbage collected. That's not what the OP is asking, he asked about *variables* being destroyed, not *objects*. You cannot easily track variables, simply because variables aren't objects in Ruby, but you can only work with objects. You will probably need to hook into the execution engine directly, using interpreter-specific code. Unfortunately, `set_trace_func` doesn't provide what you're looking for either.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, `define_finalizer` works just well for my purpose. i just need to log the object was destroyed, aka garbage collected.